# Applications of derivative

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)g(x)$ is a polynomial and $g(x)$ is nonezero for all $x$ in the closed interval between $a$ and $b$.
Prove that $g(a)g(b)$ is positive and there exist $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that derivative of $f$ at $c$ is zero.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x)$ is a polynomial, it is continuous on all real numbers. It also implies that $g(x)$ is a continuous function on all reals. Because $g(x)$ is nonzero and continuous on $[a,b]$, that means that $g(x)$ is either above or below the $x$-axis on the entire interval $[a,b]$. Can you see how this implies that $g(a)g(b)>0$?

To show the second part, notice that $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=0$. By Rolle's Theorem, since $f$ is continuous, we can conclude that the derivative of $f$ must be zero for some point $c$ between $a$ and $b$.